# jCarousel and image zoom

Tags: commerce, media, javascript

I'm using the module [image zoom](http://drupal.org/project/imagezoom) to enlarge an image with the mouse over, also I use [jCarousel](http://drupal.org/project/jcarousel) to get a carousels in different pages.

In the image zoom module you have the option to get the thumbnail of the not selected images.
example :you have a node with 6 images, one will be big and the other will be thumbnails and when you click on one of them automatically it the big image will be swapped with the clicked one.

Now automatically those thumbnail are styled with the jquery carousel, I don't mind but the problem is that I cannot change the configuration of it! I cannot change horizanotal to vertical or other settings.

How do I fix it? Should I create the jcarousel by my self and uninstall the modules or is there a solution somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described on the jCarousel module page:

> Note that you will almost certainly need to do custom CSS in your
>   theme in order to use this module.

Use Chrome Inspect, Right Click > Inspect aka Chrome Developers Tools or Even use Firebug on Firefox to inspect the applied css properties and override them in your .css file in your theme folder "sites/all/themes/themename"

A basic CSS Knowledge is what you really need.

To Change the Settings of jCarousel, Go to your views and find the "Format" Area. Make sure that the "Format" is set to jCarousel and click on "Settings" beside it. A new pop-up will open. Inside, You will find all the setting related to your jCarousel initiator.

**To change from Horizontal to Vertical scrolling, Click on the Advanced, Scroll down then Check the "Vertical" checkbox.** [See Screenshot](http://cl.ly/image/143P0t2K0F3l)

This is the most easy way to do it. If I understod your question rightly.

Comment: It's not a css issue, i cannot change the setting of the jcarousel. I need to change it. The default setting is "horizontal, 3items scroll" i need to have it vertical with 1 item scroll. I cannot do it with the css.

Comment: Syd, I added a part in the answer, On how to change the jCarousel Settings. Sorry for misunderstanding. Check the Bold Line and paragraph above.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, you got that option if you create a view. It's not a view, it's a node. I don't have the option to change the jcarousel. The system automatically create that carousel. It would be fine as long as i can change the setting. I cannot change it from "manage display" i cannot change in view because it's not a view. Try it, install image zoom and jcarousel, test it and you will see what happens.

Comment: That way you should create the jCarousel yourself, All you need is to include the jCarousel .js and .css files in your template directory and add them to template.php using drupal_add_js and drupal_add_css.

You can also use the same plugin and use the API, Read more in the API Usage in the Readme file on the Module Project Page.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I always do it manually but it was more easier with the module. Thanks for you help. I give you one vote up now and I will flag it as answer if nobody comes with the solution within one week.